# Mac OS X equivalent of "udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyACM0"

Tags: macos, usb, udev

What is the Mac OS X equivalent of the Linux command `udevadm info /dev/ttyACM0`?

I am attempting get the USB information about a TTY device (`/dev/tty.whatever`) in a script.

**UPDATE:** I'm looking for information about a TTY / serial port device (not a disk). This is the type of output I am looking for (critical fields are highlighted):

```
[rhwood@localhost ~]$ udevadm info /dev/ttyACM3
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM3
N: ttyACM3
S: digitrax-pr3-3
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/digitrax-pr3-3
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyACM3
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM3
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=tty-pci-0000_02_00_0-usb-0_2_2_1_0
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL=VC0M_Port
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=VC0M\x20Port
E: ID_MODEL_ID=ff7e
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:02:00.0-usb-0:2.2:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_02_00_0-usb-0_2_2_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0001
E: ID_SERIAL=Digitrax_Inc._VC0M_Port
E: ID_TYPE=generic
E: ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Communications
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=cdc_acm
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:020201:0a0000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=Digitrax_Inc.
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Digitrax\x20Inc.
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Microchip Technology, Inc.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=04d8
E: MAJOR=166
E: MINOR=3
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
E: TAGS=:seat:systemd:uaccess:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=292186515
```

I am really interested in matching the `DEVNAME` (`/dev/ttyACM3`) to the `VENDOR` and `MODEL` information.

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for helping clarify the question. I've removed the `-a -n` parameters for the `udevadm` command to get a less verbose output.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a little utility in python which allows the serial ports to be filtered by manufacturers, etc.
https://github.com/dhylands/usb-ser-mon/blob/master/usb_ser_mon/find_port.py

I've also recently written a serial monitor in rust, which can do a similar type of filtering/listing using the --find or --list options:
https://crates.io/crates/serial-monitor

Comment: pyudev doesn't work on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
ioreg -lp IOUSB
```

Specimen feedback from plugging in an rj45 serial cable into my ***OSX 10.14.6 Mojave*** Macbook's ***USB-C port*** is reported below:

```
+-o FT232R USB UART@14300000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x10000ee76, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (7 ms), retain 14>
    {
      "sessionID" = 573143338571350
      "iManufacturer" = 1
      "bNumConfigurations" = 1
      "idProduct" = 24577
      "bcdDevice" = 1536
      "Bus Power Available" = 250
      "USB Address" = 1
      "bMaxPacketSize0" = 8
      "iProduct" = 2
      "iSerialNumber" = 3
      "bDeviceClass" = 0
      "Built-In" = No
      "locationID" = 338690048
      "bDeviceSubClass" = 0
      "bcdUSB" = 512
      "USB Product Name" = "FT232R USB UART"
      "PortNum" = 3
      "non-removable" = "no"
      "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"9dc7b780-9ec0-11d4-a54f-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
      "bDeviceProtocol" = 0
      "IOUserClientClass" = "IOUSBDeviceUserClientV2"
      "IOPowerManagement" = {"DevicePowerState"=0,"CurrentPowerState"=3,"CapabilityFlags"=65536,"MaxPowerState"=4,"DriverPowerState"=3}
      "kUSBCurrentConfiguration" = 1
      "Device Speed" = 1
      "USB Vendor Name" = "FTDI"
      "idVendor" = 1027
      "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
      "USB Serial Number" = "A9I2IIK0"
      "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBDevice"
    }
```

I know this was posted over (4) year's ago, but noticed nobody answered it.  Hey, better late than never!  HTH-

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I have (finally!) gotten around to testing it with my own devices. This seems to work fine if the device has a serial number, but not if it doesn't.

Comment: @Randall The `-l` switch in my specimen command tells `ioreg` to "_show properties for all displayed objects_" and the `-p` switch tells `ioreg` to "_traverse the registry over the specified plane_" which in this case is `IOUSB`.  The fact that your device is not being displayed might be down to the fact the machine doesn't see it, rather than being from an empty value in the "_USB Serial Number_" string.  Otherwise, if the system could see it, I _believe_ it should appear in the output of `ioreg -lp IOUSB`. Maybe try a different USB port and a different Mac to exclude things apart from cable

Comment: The device *is* being displayed. My problem arises from not being able to tie /dev/cu.foo to a device if a serial number is not present in the device’s firmware. If the serial device is present, it seems easy.

Comment: @Randall Try the command without the `-p IOUSB` switch: I just remarked that if you omit that and just execute `ioreg -l` the output prints the device, but not the serial number for it.  Obviously the output is more verbose as it's not being limited to a single plane, but I guess you could add a grep to screen-scrape the output